# Kernel module to get network jitter and bandwidth?

Tags: linux-kernel, statistics, bandwidth, kernel-module

I need to get a list of interfaces on my local machine, along with their IP addresses, MACs and a set of QoS measurements ( Delay, Jitter, Error rate, Loss Rate, Bandwidth)...

I'm writing a kernel module to read these information from local network devices,So far I've extracted every thing mentioned above except for both Jitter and Bandwidth...

I'm using linux kernel 2.6.35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean by *bandwidth*. In most cases you only get from the PHY something that is better called *bitrate*. I guess you rather need some kind of information on the available bandwidth at a higher layer, which you can't get without active or passive measurements done, e.g. sending ICMP echo-like probe packets, and investigating replies. You should also make clear what the two points in the network are (both the actual endpoints and the communication layer) between which you would like to measure available bandwidth.

As for *jitter* you also need to do some kind of measurements, basically the same way as above.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but you could accomplish at least getting jitter by inspecting the RTCP packets if they're available. They come in on the +1 of the RTP port and come along with any RTP stream as far as I've seen. A lot of information can be gotten from RTCP, but for your purposes just the basic source description would do it:

**EDIT**: (didn't look at the preview)

Just check out this [link](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3550.txt) for the details of the protocol, but you can get the jitter pretty easily from an RTCP packet.

Depending on what you're using the RTP stream for too there are a lot of other resources, like the VoIP Metrics Report Block in the Extended Report (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3611#page-25).

**EDIT**:

As per Artem's request here is a basic flow of how you might do it:

1. An RTP stream is started on say port 16400 (the needed drivers/mechanism for this to happen are most likely already in place).
2. Tell the kernel to start listening on port 16401 (1 above your RTP stream's port) as well; this is where the RTCP pkts will start coming in.
3. As the RTCP pkts come in send them wherever you want to handle them (ie, if you're wanting to parse it in userspace or something).
4. Parse the pkts for the desired data. I'm not aware of a particular lib to do this, but it's pretty easy to just point some struct at it (in C) and dereference, watching out for Endianess.

Comment: Could you elaborate more and put some code/action flow for your post?